# How to print generated assembly code for intrinsic functions in the "java.lang.Math"?

Tags: java, jvm, vectorization, jvm-hotspot, vector-search

I am experimenting on vector similarity search algorithms with Java Panama Vector API. And I am trying to understand how some calls (for example `Math.fma`) are generated to assembly code on different platforms. I know they are JVM intrinsic functions, but I couldn't see the generated machine code for those functions when I enabled printing assembly code (`-XX:+PrintAssembly` and/or `-XX:CompileCommand`).

How can I see the generated assembly code for intrinsic functions in the `java.lang.Math`?

Comment: Look at the assembly code of the *caller*.